# Hosting multiple Wordpress sites on single server - best practices?

Tags: linux, hosting, configuration

I rent some webserver space (Linux, MySql, PHP, Apache) and host several Wordpress websites (for different clients, with different needs)
What would be the best way to Host multiple wordpress sites on a single machine, what I'm looking for here, is saving on diskspace and number of databases needed as well as simplifying maintenance.

- Yes this should be for a single wordpress version.
- Each site should be able to have different plugins included and activated
- Each site should be able to have it's own themes (some shared some not)
- No crossing between sites - users and content not shared in any way.
- Easily Upgradable
- Single Super Admin is a plus but not essential
  (I know how to install and manage wordpress, I can't figure out if Wordpress MU is what I need, if so how to set it up so that my requirements are met, can I enable/disable features per user/blog created with MU).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your needs, yes: you should probably be using a Network (WordPress with MultiSite enabled).

- All network sites run the same version of WordPress
- Each network site can activate its own Plugins. You can explicitly allow each site to manage its own Plugins.
- Each network site can have access to different Themes (though you will have to manage access to each Theme via the Network Admin.
- Users can be managed such that each sites users are mutually exclusive
- Upgrades of WordPress core, Themes, Plugins, and network sites is all managed from a single location in the Network Admin
- Super Admin is part of a Network install, and allows granular control over each network site, Plugins, Themes, and users.

As for how to set up a Network, [everything is incredibly well-documented in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Comment: I guess this answers my questions... Lets see if I know how to read :-) Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I was able to follow the Codex instructions - so I'm assuming that just about anyone else can, too. ;)

Comment: Bennet I followed the instructions to the dot, it worked perfectly, I now use the MU solution for a easy development and production platform - avoiding the need to install WP for every new client site (with new DB etc...).
Additional Benefits:
Single location for adding themes
Single location for adding plugins
Easy updating of components (core, plugins, themes)
Easy backup of entire installation and specific sites.
Huge space saver on hosting.

I have yet to experience performance problems, but again, these are not huge sites.

Comment: After over 6 months of using Wordpress Network configuration I can indeed confirm that this was exactly what I was looking for at the time. It is super easy to install and manage, network admins can work the entire network, but each single site/blog has it's own users without conflicts between the sites. It supports having either a subdomain or directory for each site (you need to choose a single configuration for the entire network) but you can also easily use dedicated domains to access each site. Saves a ton of space (only one install DIR and db). Highly recommended.

Comment: @MosheEshel what do you use for dedicated domains? redirects or a plugin?

Comment: @IvanRF This is very old... I haven't used multisite in years. Originally I used it for supporting multiple sites on a single install since I had one hosting account. I seem to recall there was a domain management plugin, can't remember the name.
Since then I move to having a reseller account where I can set each client in his own hosting account, so I moved to the regular wordpress install. This resolves a lot of issues (maintenance windows, client account access and more). Still for certain use cases multisite is an excellent solution.